# Delete string from names in sublists

Tags: r, gsub

I have a list of lists I need to delete "gene-" everywhere where it happens.
I tried

```
 lapply(net, FUN = function(x) setNames(x, sub("gene-","", x)))
```

but I get the error

> Error in names(object) <- nm : attempt to set an attribute on NULL

```
 head(net)
$colors
        gene-AAAS         gene-AAK1        gene-AAMDC         gene-AAMP        gene-AARS1        gene-AASDH 
        "magenta"           "brown"          "purple"        "darkgrey"           "brown"            "blue" 
    gene-AASDHPPT         gene-AASS         gene-AATK         gene-ABAT        
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 8990 entries ]

$unmergedColors
        gene-AAAS         gene-AAK1        gene-AAMDC         gene-AAMP        gene-AARS1        gene-AASDH 
       "darkgrey"            "blue"         "magenta"  "darkolivegreen"            "blue"           "brown" 
    gene-AASDHPPT         gene-AASS         gene-AATK         gene-ABAT        gene-ABCA1       gene-ABCA12 
    "lightyellow"      "lightgreen"       "turquoise"         "darkred"       "turquoise"          "grey60" 

 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 8990 entries ]

$MEs
        MEblack MEgreenyellow MElightcyan    MEyellow MEturquoise      MEpink     MEwhite   MEdarkred
M5  -0.17423916   0.141440817  0.23401244  0.36358728  -0.0220835 -0.18126013  0.05942248 -0.45035371
N3   0.47690393   0.428961135  0.07241255 -0.02557197   0.2238352  0.06742087 -0.09574663  0.52201599

          
$goodSamples
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

$goodGenes
   [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 8990 entries ]

$dendrograms
$dendrograms[[1]]

Call:
fastcluster::hclust(d = as.dist(dissTom), method = "average")

Cluster method   : average 
Number of objects: 9990
```

dput(net)

```
    166L, 5768L, 2346L, 7132L, 625L, 4848L, 736L, 7001L, 
    1721L, 6626L, 7674L, 2543L, 7013L, 8667L, 4593L, 2804L,
```

....

```
7435L, 4895L, 8462L, 1732L, 3160L, 8529L), labels = NULL, 
        method = "average", call = fastcluster::hclust(d = as.dist(dissTom), 
            method = "average"), dist.method = NULL), class = "hclust")), 
    TOMFiles = NULL, blockGenes = list(1:9990), blocks = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
```

...

```
1, 1), MEsOK = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you share `dput(net)` please? Or at least a portion of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost works, you need two changes:

1. You want to modify the *names*, so your inner function needs to read `names(x)`:

   ```
   function(x) setNames(x, sub("gene-", "", names(x)))
   ```
2. `net` contains a lot of members. You only want to replace the `colors` and `unmergedColors` members, so apply your function to only those. Oh, and you need to assign the result back to your object:

   ```
   which = c("colors", "unmergedColors")
   net[which] = lapply(net[which], function(x) setNames(x, sub("gene-", "", names(x))))
   ```